# Spatial polygon plots in wrong location on map background

Tags: r, polygon, raster

I want to plot the utilization distributions of two animals on a spatial map background and calculate area overlap. However, for some reason, although both layers have the same projection, one is off (plotted too far to the east). Consequently, any overlap I calculate then is incorrect.

So my question is what causes this issue and how can I fix this?

Below are my two rasters, transformed to `SpatialPolygons` so that I could use `gIntersection()` to calculate overlap. Note that while `p1` plots just fine, `p2` does not.

```
p1 <- class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 549 
extent      : 667950.6, 672950.6, 2840181, 2853981  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 

p2 <- class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 257 
extent      : 670158.7, 673958.7, 2839623, 2851623  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Below pic shows how the polygons are currently plotted. p1 is depicted in green, and p2 is in red.

[image]

Desired plotting location for p2 should look like this (this plot is created in `ggplot2` from the same raster file):

[image]

I thought maybe it was because the extents are so different. So I extended the areas of both rasters to the same extent, after which I converted them to polygons and plotted. But this does not solve anything.

EDIT: rasters `r1` and `r2` that can be converted to `SpatialPolygons` using `as(x, 'SpatialPolygons')` can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDYk-bugvWrdfeh_wU6-YrDbvLo50-2z/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qKA4JZ5RJGpQaeLLJGALJ-KngsWdDBsH/view?usp=sharing).

EDIT 2: The crs for both rasters should be:

```
"+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

EDIT 3: If it helps, the two rasters in question were generated by combining 2 sub-region rasters (central and north) after first extending the spatial extents of each raster to the spatial extent shared by both rasters and then rescaling to range from 0 to 1. However, some other rasters (not included here) are made up from 3 sub-region rasters. I don't know why this could matter, as the projections of the rasters are the same, so therefore should lead to correct spatial plots?

EDIT 4: Region rasters that were used to create r1 can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8CRahsOE2vhEyaMGSvCuBdHMv1Znofc/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLKKwPSQ3PLzeE8BLr0MpA28Bvgh-Ygf/view?usp=sharing). Similarly, region rasters for r2 are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H2towgJ2h7kH7Atnjq7YiP0K270X9bWa/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CkXp6VeKxSx3eBxFKppNcuALddKfN3qJ/view?usp=sharing).

EDIT 5: Below the code that i used to generate the output. Sorry for not introducing this earlier. `r1` and `r2` provided in the links are identical to `r1.recl` and `r2.recl` where the 0's have been replaced by NA.

```
     library(magrittr)
aeqd.crs <- "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=25.6871 +lon_0=-79.29336 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" #aeqd is original CRS
    UTMstring <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" # crs of study site shapefile
        r1 = raster("r1")
        proj4string(r1) <- CRS(aeqd.crs)
        r1 %<>% raster::setMinMax()   
        r1 <- projectRaster(r1, crs = UTMstring) 
        r1[is.na(r1)] <- 0
        r1 <- r1 / max(r1@data@values)
        recl <- matrix(data = c(0, 0.05, 0,
                                0.05, 1, 1), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
        r1.recl <- reclassify(r1, recl)
        r1.recl[r1.recl == 0] <- NA
        r2 = raster("r2")
        proj4string(r2) <- CRS(aeqd.crs) 
        r2 %<>% raster::setMinMax()
        r2 <- projectRaster(r2, crs = UTMstring)
        r2[is.na(r2)] <- 0
        r2 <- r2 / max(r2@data@values)
        r2.recl <- reclassify(r2, recl)
        r2.recl[r2.recl == 0] <- NA
        
        # convert rasters to spatial polygons; vector shapes give access to spatial tools in the {rgeos} package
        p1 <- as(r1.recl, 'SpatialPolygons')
        p2 <- as(r2.recl, 'SpatialPolygons')
        
    overlap <- gIntersection(p1, p2) # Creates raster
    
        # Calculate common area
        plot(p1, col = "green")
        plot(p2, col = "red", add = TRUE)
    plot(overlap, col = "orange", add = TRUE)
        
        # calculate area of overlap (in m2)
        common.area <- gArea(overlap) / (1000^2)
        common.area
[1] 92716.54
```

Comment: Data links would be helpful here.

Comment: Perhaps take us back to setting coord ref on the `r1` and `r2`, as the .asc(s) for download are not set, or what template was used.

Comment: And I guess I'm also interested in the source for `r2` observations, as even with `project`ing, r1 and r2 to common crs, extent & etc, these fish(or birds, I'm guessing) are stubbornly on land...

Comment: @Chris I added the CRS for both rasters. The animals in question are sharks. Does this answer your question? Added also a 3rd edit that describes how each raster was generated.

Comment: Would the original north, central and south for both be available, even r2 central was without data?

Comment: @Chris Added links to OP. I realised that actually r1 is also made up of only 2 sub-region rasters.. Not sure though why it looks like it's plotted correctly. But perhaps none of them are. I found another post that may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930336/calculating-area-of-overlap-between-2-raster-layers-with-different-origins-and-e. However, resampling both rasters didn't change results either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248947/discussion-between-flyingdutch-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches to compute overlap with your data.

Your data

```
library(terra)
prj <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
r1 <- rast("r1.asc")
crs(r1) <- prj
r2 <- rast("r2.asc")
crs(r2) <- prj
```

The "raster" approach

```
e <- union(ext(r1), ext(r2))
x1 <- extend(r1, e)
x2 <- resample(r2, x1) + 1
y <- sum(c(x1, x2), na.rm=TRUE)    
a <- cellSize(y)
zonal(a, y, "sum")
#  sum        area
#1   1 21881870.89
#2   2 10200711.13
#3   3    80006.73
```

Where "1" is the area covered by species `r1`, "2" by `r2` and "3" by both.

You can also assume a fixed nominal resolution. In this case that is only a little less precise (but that is not always the case)

```
f <- freq(y)
f$area <- f$count * prod(res(y))
f[,-1]
#  value count     area
#1     1   547 21880000
#2     2   255 10200000
#3     3     2    80000
```

The "vector" approach

```
p1 <- as.polygons(r1)
p2 <- as.polygons(r2)
p <- union(p1, p2)
p$area <- expanse(p)
data.frame(p)
#  r1 r2        area
#1  1  1    92724.32
#2  1 NA 21869156.44
#3 NA  1 10187993.21
```

You could also do

```
intersect(p1, p2) |> expanse()
#[1] 92724.32
```

The results are similar for the raster and vector approach, but not the same. This is because the raster data are not aligned, which suggests that you could improve how these were created.

Plotting the two species shows the same pattern you have

```
p1$sp <- "1"
p2$sp <- "2"
p <- rbind(p1, p2)
plot(p, "sp")
```

And I can more-or-less reproduce `r1` and `r2` (but I need to guess things, in the future please describe your procedures with code, not with natural language) :

```
bn = rast("bull_North.asc")
bs = rast("bull_South.asc")
rn = rast("reef_North.asc")
rs = rast("reef_South.asc")
b2 = bn + bs
r2 = rn + rs
e <- intersect(ext(b2), ext(r2))
b <- crop(b2, e)
r <- crop(r2, e)
b <- ifel(b>0.05, 1, NA)
r <- ifel(r>0.05, 1, NA)
plot(b, col="blue")
plot(r, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

So, clearly the problem is already present in the original data.

Comment: I've been getting those red & blue plots all day for evolving iterations of levels of data stages, with an 'intuition' that it entered even earlier, and heartened to hear you say 'clearly already present'. And the above provides, to me, the roadmap that I'd have hoped to execute to arrive at the same conclusion, given data provided to this point. And telemetry mediated by utilization distributions (in chat), well, how bout just providing telemetry point data prior to that. Then waltz it thru the UD process to see where that took things, bug or feature. `union(ext...` thanks.

Comment: Apologies for not providing code earlier, but is added now. I realise now that my code is overly complicated so thank you for showing me a more efficient way. Nevertheless, as you point out, because we arrive at the same incorrect plots, the issue must lie not with how we code things. I'll have to think where it could have gone wrong.